# Django Template: How to check if a variable is in another variable?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Beginner in Django here  ,

I want to check if a particular string variable is in another variable inside the for loop.

`a = 'abc' b = 'abcd'` 
I have tried below codes:-

`{% if a in b %}`
`{% if '{{a}}' in b %}`
`{% if '{{a}}' in '{{b}}' %}`

But none of them seem to work , can anybody guide me here please ?

Comment: `{% if a in b %}` should work. Have you verified that a is _actually_ in b? :)

Comment: @CmdrSharp
Yes , I have verified it. When i print using <p> , They show something like this :- `b= 1131 in 1131-your-file-name.pnh

a = 1131`

Comment: The code you provided should work, could you show us a minimal reproducible example of the relevant view method so we see how you defined the variables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.